# Safest way to connect to TOR

Tags: vpn

I'm getting mixed messages on connecting to TOR.

1. Should I use a vpn over a bridge?
2. Any other options?
3. Can I still be tracked

Trying to keep my connection to tor private.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd rather use just a VPN - it will provide an equal privacy without an overhead. After that - yes, you can use a bridge *through* VPN to connect to Tor network, it may add some anonymity to you.
2. Quite a lot! It depends on specific situation that you're experiencing
3. Always :) The question is - how laborious it is